# Is there a way to make row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor fixed, despite repaintings?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, datagridview

Right now I am using the following to color my datagridview rows:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if ((row.Index % 2) == 0)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.NavajoWhite;
    }
}
```

which is fine for when the data loads up first time. However, I am also using a third party library to filter columns like Excel does (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33786/DataGridView-Filter-Popup). It works great, however the problem is that this code **repaints** the datagridview on every filtering applied (to plain white). I can catch the necessary event to repaint my rows after every filtering, if I so wish, for example

```
dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
```

however if I have large matrices (hundreds of thousands of lines) that is terribly inefficient.

The question is whether there is a way to make row background color **fixed**, despite the repaintings done by the filtering. It seems to me like that might be a long shot, so any advice to tackle this problem or make it faster and more efficient, would be appreciated.

Comment: Standard way of doing any kind of visual styling on DGV is it's [CellPaint Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @bokibeg This was one of the first things I tried, however it's even more inefficient than the RowPostPaint event (dependent on the number of columns).

Comment: @lason try pasting your paint code, if you're changing its style on every iteration it can be very slow indeed. Have you tried applying the [example from RowPrePaint event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? It's using Gdi+ and already doing  pretty much what you need.

Comment: @bokibeg Thanks for the link. Can you please elaborate how I can make that do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try handle only `CellPainting` event for each cell

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender,
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
     if ((e.RowIndex % 2) == 0)         
         e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.NavajoWhite;         
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately this doesn't help me much. It triggers an event even when you scroll through the datagridview, which the user will, since it is thousands of lines long.

Comment: @Iason, this event is triggered often but only for currently visible cells, which have to be painted. and `if ((row.Index % 2) == 0)  e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.NavajoWhite;` is a very simple check, which doesn't cost much. i have used this code on grids with 100K+ rows without any performance issues. Do you do something else in painting event handlers?

Comment: No, I don't think I am doing anything else in the code. The difference is that, because I have 3 datagridviews, I do this repainting for each one of my grids. So 3 foreach loops instead of 1(not nested). But I'm not doing anything else in any paint event handlers.

Comment: And for some reason, even when I scrolled through the rows just for a 20k row matrix, it was exxtremely slow.

Comment: @Iason, try only handle `CellPainting` events on your grids. Do not set `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` for all rows in foreach at all (comment or remove your code `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {if ((row.Index % 2) == 0) e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.NavajoWhite; }`)

Comment: @Iason, i have tried `dataGridView1_CellPainting` in a new Winforms project with 1 form on a grid with 3 columns x 20K row. (Fixed a typo, it should be `e.RowIndex`). It has worked as expected: alternated white and red rows. If it doesn't work for you, can you also try it in a new form on a test grid?

Comment: Yes, it worked and was magnitudes faster than handling the RowPostPaint event. I guess because I was going through the whole lines of my matrix, repainting them, each time I filtered.

Answer (score 1):

After trying out [the MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85kxk29c(v=vs.110).aspx) myself I found out it's not so easy, it's been a long time since I worked with DataGridView so here goes.

Below example provide alternate row background regardless of cell's style gimmicks. Just place a grid on the form and call this method in Form's constructor:

```
private void InitializeGrid()
{
    dgv.Columns.Add("colId", "Id");
    dgv.Columns.Add("colName", "Name");

    for (int c = 1; c <= 100; c++)
    {
        int r = dgv.Rows.Add();
        dgv.Rows[r].SetValues(c, "Person" + c);
    }

    dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
}
```

It will create an example grid which you can tinker with.

Now here's the interesting bit:

```
private void dgv_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Don't paint focused/selected rows
    if ((e.State & DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) ==
                DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
        return;

    // This informs the event that we don't want it to paint the background, we'll take 
    // care of it instead.
    e.PaintParts &= ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Background;

    // Calculate row rectangle (based off the MSDN example)
    var rowBounds = new Rectangle(
        dgv.RowHeadersWidth, e.RowBounds.Top,
        dgv.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) - dgv.HorizontalScrollingOffset + 1,
        e.RowBounds.Height);

    // Paint row headers, for some reason they are part of the Background.
    e.PaintHeader(true);

    // Now custom-paint the row background
    using (Brush backBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.NavajoWhite))
    {
        if (e.RowIndex % 2 != 0)
            // If RowIndex is not divisible by 2 then paint custom color
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backBrush, rowBounds);
        else
            // Otherwise just let the grid paint the row
            e.PaintCells(rowBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Background);
    }
}
```

Make sure you also have `using System.Drawing;` directive. Note that this example will only work properly with `dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;`. For regular cell-selection mode it's a bit trickier, you have to handle that scenario as well.

The rendering is very fast and should help you accomplish the task. If not then at least you have more options to consider. Changing cell's style at appropriate times should also work fine but may result in flicker or affect responsiveness.

Comment: Thank you for this. From my testing (20k rows, 260k rows), I think it was just a little slower than handling the cell painting event. However it was much faster than handling the RowPostPaint event.